# Jupyter Notebook - Bokeh Server Plots Won't Display in PyCharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, bokeh

In PyCharm, this visualization displays in PyCharm right within the notebook file:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show

output_notebook()

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

p = figure(x_axis_label="x", y_axis_label="y")

p.line(x, y, line_width=2)

show(p)
```

However, using a bokeh server-based app, this visualization does not appear within the notebook in PyCharm:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show

output_notebook()

def my_app(doc):
    a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    b = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

    app_plot = figure(x_axis_label="a", y_axis_label="b")

    app_plot.line(a, b, line_width=2)

    doc.add_root(app_plot)

show(my_app)
```

In both cases, the bokeh logo displays along with the text next to it that reads "BoekhJS successfully loaded".

In the second case, I can have PyCharm load the notebook in a browser and the visualization displays fine there.

In the second case, this message shows up in the Jupyter server tab:
WARNING:tornado.access:403 GET /ws?url=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A63342%2Fws_jupyter%3Fuuid%3D87094e8d-5442-46cc-9dce-2e5aab3f8ebc&darcula=true&trusted=true&_ijt=tcbmdcgsoqdkpgfmpqaognmvl1 (::1) 3.00ms